# What is the matrix of self and the outside world, evil and good?

Tags: self, moral-psychology, recognition

I remember that there is a matrix in my textbook when I studied the basic psychology in colleage. The four 4 quadrants are 1) self is good and the outside world is also good; 2) self is evil but the outside is good; 3) self is good but the outside is evil; 4) self is evil and the outside is also evil. I have searched it for days but cannot find it.

Could anyone please tell me what that matrix is? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not totally match your description (the person's [worldview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_view), the evilness of the viewed objects), but it's quite analogous to the **table of style of attachment**, so I put it here.

[image]

I do notice that the major topic in the [attachment theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_theory) is about relationship, while the topics in your description seem to be about moral in general, but I suspect that yours discusses about interpersonal relationships as well.

The image is captured from the book [Interpersonal Communication: Everyday Encounters, 8th Edition](https://www.cengage.com/c/interpersonal-communication-everyday-encounters-8e-wood/9781285445830). The original research is Butzer & Campbell, 2008.

One minor note: I see that many people use the word "matrix" as a synonym of "table". Technically, a matrix is a table of numbers, but not a table of ideas.

Comment: OK, great, thanks. I borrowed "matrix" from "Eisenhower Matrix".